# NHibernate/Transaction how commit only one object and not the entire session

Tags: c#, mysql, list, session, nhibernate

My problem is when I want to update only one object in the database, every object in my list are updated in the database. I load the list with the same session and I can't make an other session to make my update because I got an error : illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions nhibernate.

There is my code that I use to make the update.

```
private ISession session = NHibernateConnexion.OpenSession();
using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Update(item);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Item is the object that I want to update.

The code that I use to load the entire list:

```
public IList<Item> RetrieveAll()
{
    var result = from i in session.Query<Item>()
                 orderby i.EstActif descending
                 select i;

    IList<Item> listeTemp = result.ToList();
    return listeTemp;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Save in new session

   What you doing is right, but the only thing is, you need the evict the entity from session using which you fetched the data. Do something like this

   ```
   sessionWhichFetchedTheData.evict(item)

   private ISession session = NHibernateConnexion.OpenSession();
   using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction()
   {
       session.Update(item);
       transaction.Commit();
   }
   ```
2. Save in current session but clear the session before saving

   ```
   session.clear()
   sessionThatFetchedTheData.SaveOrUpdate(item)
   ```